# coordinate Hopf algebra and algebraic group

Tags: category-theory, algebraic-groups, hopf-algebras

I have an algebraic group (a representable functor) $(G,\mu,\eta,\sigma)$ and it's coordinate algebra ${\cal{O}}(G)$.

In my course it is stated without proof that the category of algebraic groups ${\bf{AlgGrp}}_k$ is anti-equivalent to the category of Hopf algebras ${\bf{Hpf}}_k$.

I would like two know which are the two functors that work.

One is easy

$$F:{\bf{Hpf}}_k^{op}\rightarrow {\bf{AlgGrp}}_k
\\H\mapsto (\text{Hom}_{Alg}(H,-),\mu,\eta,\sigma)\\f\mapsto\bar{f}\text{        where  }\bar{f}(\phi) = \phi\circ f$$

with $\mu,\eta,\sigma$ given by the rules of $H$.

However defining the opposite functor is proving more difficult.

Any help?

Comment: One should note that the equivalence is between the category of Hopf algebras and the category of *affine* algebraic groups. The opposite functor is just the coordinate algebra $G\mapsto\mathcal{O}(G)$. This is just a restriction of the standard anti-equivalence between $k$-algebras and affine schemes.

Comment: yes in our course affine algebraic groups and algebraic groups are the same. However, the question (which was not very precise) is how does the opposite functors act on functions. Can we say more as in the case of the functor I gave where the image of a function is clearly defined?

Answer (score 3):

The precise equivalence is between affine group schemes over $k$ and the opposite of commutative Hopf algebras over $k$. ("Algebraic group" is a very ambiguous term - for most people it means the underlying scheme has finite type, and for some people it has to be a variety - and noncommutative Hopf algebras don't enter the story.) It goes like this:

1. The category of affine schemes over $k$ is equivalent to the opposite of the category of commutative $k$-algebras. This is either a definition or a theorem depending on your definition of affine schemes.
2. An affine group scheme over $k$ is a group object in the category of affine schemes over $k$.
3. A commutative Hopf algebra over $k$ is a *cogroup* object in the category of commutative $k$-algebras. (This is not true if "commutative" is dropped!)

The functor from affine group schemes to Hopf algebras is given by taking the coordinate algebra, which for any scheme $X$ is given by $\text{Hom}_{\text{Sch}}(X, \mathbb{A}^1)$.